# How to set start value as “0” in Chart.js Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, chart.js

I'm using Chart.js in my Laravel project and I don't know how I can set my chart at zero.

```php
$chartjs = app()->chartjs
    ->name('lineChartTest')
    ->type('bar')
    ->size(['width' => 400, 'height' => 200])
    ->labels(['02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11'])
    ->datasets([
        [
            'label' => 'My Second Dataset',
            'backgroundColor' => 'rgba(138, 22, 54, 0.31)',
            'borderColor' => 'rgba(138, 125, 154, 0.7)',
            'pointBorderColor' => 'rgba(38, 285, 14, 0.7)',
            'pointBackgroundColor' => 'rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)',
            'pointHoverBackgroundColor' => '#fff',
            'pointHoverBorderColor' => 'rgba(120,20,220,1)',
            'data' => [
                $articles['02']->count(), $articles['03']->count(), $articles['04']->count(), $articles['05']->count(),
                $articles['06']->count(), $articles['07']->count(), $articles['08']->count(), $articles['09']->count(),
                $articles['10']->count(), $articles['11']->count()
            ],
            'borderWidth' => 3,
        ]

    ])
    ->options([]);
```

Comment: can you specify the laravel version and the https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts version  or specify the chart package you are using

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/

Comment: @Manojkiran.A   laravel v 5.8 chartjs v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to set the `beginAtZero` option:

```
$chartOptions = [
    'scales' => [
        'yAxes' => [
            [
                'ticks' => [
                    'beginAtZero' => true,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

->options($chartOptions);
```

Comment: it gives me this error for that empty array "only variables can be passed by reference"

Answer (score 0):

If you want the y-axis to start at zero you can include it in the options

```
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
    }
}
```